# error: initializer element is not constant in C

Tags: c

Here i am trying to make state machine where FsmHdlr should call a appropriate function based on state and event. What i am getting the above error. How to resolve this.

```
   S16 handleParamReqEvt(void)
    {
      /* doing something */
      RETVALUE(ROK);    
    }

    S16 handleParamRspEvt(param_resp *paramRsp) 
    {
      /* doing something */
      RETVALUE(ROK);    
    }

    typedef enum{
      IDLE,
      CONFIGURED,
      MAX_STATE
    }STATE;

    /* Events in CL */
    typedef enum{
      PARAM_REQ,
      PARAM_RSP 
      MAX_EVENT
    }EVENT;

    param_resp *paramMsg;

    S16 FsmHdlr[MAX_STATE][MAX_EVENT] = 
    {
      {
        /* PHY_STATE_IDLE */
        handleParamReqEvt(),           //error :initializer element is not constant
        handleParamRspEvt(paramMsg)    //error: initializer element is not constant
      }
    };
```

Comment: `FsmHdlr` is this global variable ? Otherwise this error doesn't make sense. Please provide [mcve].

Comment: what is `S16`? What is `RETVALUE`? What is `ROK`?

Comment: yes FsmFdlr is global here.
since the code is lengthy i couldn't paste the entire thing
S16 is int type
Retvalue (rok) is return 0

Comment: Are you trying to compile legacy code or these are your local changes ? To me `FsmHdlr` should be a function pointer or array of function pointer depends upon input.

Comment: @MAMTHASRI Well its is not possible atleast in `c` unless you store function pointer instead of its return.

Comment: can u please give me a example to do so ? @Achal

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you don't actually want to call the function during initialization (which you can't do for static storage variables anyway, as you've discovered). It sounds like you are building a dispatch table. What you want is called a function pointer.

This how one uses function pointers:

```
int foo(void) { ... }

int main(void) {
   int (*bar)(void) = foo;
   bar();  // Calls foo
}
```

Since the parameters vary based on the type of the event, a 2d array doesn't make much sense. I'd use the following in your case:

```
S16 fsm_hdrl_idle_param_req(void)                { ... }
S16 fsm_hdrl_idle_param_rsp(ParamRsp *param_rsp) { ... }
S16 fsm_hdrl_conf_param_req(void)                { ... }
S16 fsm_hdrl_conf_param_rsp(ParamRsp *param_rsp) { ... }

typedef S16 (*FsmReqHdlr)(void);
typedef S16 (*FsmRspHdlr)(ParamRsp*);

typedef struct {
   FsmReqHdlr fsm_req_hdlr;
   FsmRspHdlr fsm_rsp_hdlr;
} FsmHdlrs;

FsmHdlrs fsm_hdlrs_by_state[MAX_STATE] = {
   { fsm_hdrl_idle_param_req, fsm_hdrl_idle_param_rsp },
   { fsm_hdrl_conf_param_req, fsm_hdrl_conf_param_rsp },
};
```

Later:

```
fsm_hdlrs_by_state[state].fsm_req_hdlr();

fsm_hdlrs_by_state[state].fsm_rsp_hdlr(param_rsp);
```

Comment: OP has two functions with two different signature, I think your approach won't suite.

Comment: @kiran Biradar, I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could declare pointer to `FsmHdlr[MAX_STATE][MAX_EVENT]` as a global variable.

```
S16 (*FsmHdlr)[MAX_STATE][MAX_EVENT] = NULL;
```

Somewhere in `main` function allocate the memory to the global pointer as below.

```
FsmHdlr = malloc(sizeof(S16 [MAX_STATE][MAX_EVENT]));
```

Then use `memcpy` to copy array compound literal as below.

```
   memcpy(FsmHdlr,
         (S16 [MAX_STATE][MAX_EVENT])    {
             {
                 /* PHY_STATE_IDLE */
                handleParamReqEvt(), handleParamRspEvt(paramMsg) 
             }
           },
         sizeof((S16 [MAX_STATE][MAX_EVENT])    {
             {
                 /* PHY_STATE_IDLE */
                handleParamReqEvt(), handleParamRspEvt(paramMsg) 
             }
           })
   );
```

And dereference as below,

```
(*FsmHdlr)[0][0];//to access 1st element
(*FsmHdlr)[0][1];//to access 2nd element
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot initialise array during declaration using values, what are unknown while compilation.
And, your initialization values are values returned by handleParamReqEvt() and handleParamRspEvt(...), what are unknown.
I suppose that you are thinking about pointers to these functions, nor function values.
So, you should use function names instead of function calls, like below:

```
S16 FsmHdlr[MAX_STATE][MAX_EVENT] = 
{
  {
    /* PHY_STATE_IDLE */
    handleParamReqEvt,   //initializer element is NOW constant
    handleParamRspEvt    //initializer element is NOW constant
  }
};
```

Unfortunately, this will not compile because of wrong array type - now it is not S16[][] (or S16**) like before.
Additionaly, both pointers are pointers of different types:
 - first is S16 ( * )();
 - second is S16 ( * )(param_resp*);
Fortunately, you can store them both as void* (pointer to anything), but remember that you MUST PROPERLY CAST them before usage.
For cast simplification you can declare the types of these function using typedef directive.

So, the final form of declaration+initialization and usage will be:

```
// declaration + initialisation of array
void* FsmHdlr[MAX_STATE][MAX_EVENT] = 
{
  {
    /* PHY_STATE_IDLE */
    handleParamReqEvt,
    handleParamRspEvt
  }
};

// declaration of types
typedef S16 (*reqEvt_ptr)();            //signature of handleParamReqEvt()
typedef S16 (*rspEvt_ptr)(param_resp*); //signature of handleParamRspEvt(param_resp*)

// usage:
// handleParamReqEvt
reqEvt_ptr reqEvt = (reqEvt_ptr)FsmHdlr[/* index here */][PARAM_REQ]; // cast
S16 reqResult = reqEvt(); // call
// handleParamRspEvt
rspEvt_ptr rspEvt = (rspEvt_ptr)FsmHdlr[/* index here */][PARAM_RSP]; // cast
S16 rspResult = rspEvt(/* pointer to paramMsg here */); // call
```